# Caption outside float

Tags: floats, captions

I have the below mentioned code and it is giving me caption outside float error. Kindly advise as to why am I getting this error.

```
\begin{center}
\caption{
Table 10. Performance for the seven models using the top 10 features from model D3 on the test dataset. \label{long}}\\
\vspace{15}
\begin{tabular}{|c c c|} 
 \hline
 Models & AUC & RMSE  \\ [0.5ex] 
 \hline\hline
M1 & 0.640431 & 0.459820 \\
 \hline\hline
M2 & 0.980599 & 0.179471 \\
 \hline\hline
M3 & 0.985183 & 0.112334 \\
 \hline\hline
D1 & 0.712025 & 0.158077 \\
 \hline\hline
D2 & 0.838344 & 0.120950 \\
 \hline\hline
D3 & 0.753037 & 0.117660 \\
 \hline\hline
D4 & 0.711824 & 0.814445\\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\vspace{15pt}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! You can use `captionof{table}{<caption text>}` defined in in the packages `caption` and `capt-of`.

Comment: To answer your question, you get that error message because  `\@captype` is undefined (instead of figure or table).

Answer (score 3):

Just wrap your `tabular` environment in a `table` environment which is a floating entity that can have `caption` and `label`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
    \listoftables
    
    \vspace{2cm}
    
    \begin{table}[ht]
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{|c c c|} 
            \hline
            Models & AUC & RMSE  \\ [0.5ex] 
            \hline\hline
            M1 & 0.640431 & 0.459820 \\
            \hline\hline
            M2 & 0.980599 & 0.179471 \\
            \hline\hline
            M3 & 0.985183 & 0.112334 \\
            \hline\hline
            D1 & 0.712025 & 0.158077 \\
            \hline\hline
            D2 & 0.838344 & 0.120950 \\
            \hline\hline
            D3 & 0.753037 & 0.117660 \\
            \hline\hline
            D4 & 0.711824 & 0.814445\\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
        %Previous method: \renewcommand\thetable{10} %If you want to change the table number manually
        \setcounter{table}{9} %If you want to change the table number manually
        \caption{Performance for the seven models using the top 10 features from model D3 on the test dataset.}
        \label{table::long}
    \end{table}
    
    This is a reference, \ref{table::long}.
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** Added `\centering` which I forgot to do, and changed the method of renumbering. Thanks to @Mico's comments.

[image]

Comment: To replicate the horizontal centering performed in OP's code, you should provide a `\centering` directive between `\begin{table}` and `\begin{tabular}`.

Comment: Setting the `table` counter to a constant, via `\renewcommand\thetable{10}`, is poor advice to future readers of your posting. Running `\setcounter{table}{9}` is much less likely to be misunderstood.

Comment: @Mico Good points.